# RuntimeException while uploading from Firebase storage

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, runtimeexception

I tried to upload image from firebase storage and the url already exist but the code crashed when run. It gives `RuntimeException` on the `init()` method.

my kt code :

```
private fun init() {
if (Common.currentUser !=null && Common.currentUser!!.avatar !=null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(Common.currentUser!!.avatar))
{
    Glide.with(this).load(Common.currentUser!!.avatar).into(image_avatar)
    //Toast.makeText(this,"Error "+Common.currentUser!!.avatar,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    //Snackbar.make(drawerLayout,"Error "+Common.currentUser!!.avatar,Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}}
```

**Log:**

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.crazytaxi/com.example.crazytaxi.DriverHomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument must not be null
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3961)
```

at com.example.crazytaxi.DriverHomeActivity.init(DriverHomeActivity.kt:118)
at com.example.crazytaxi.DriverHomeActivity.onCreate(DriverHomeActivity.kt:68)

Comment: Is `image_avatar` on the screen when you set click listener for it?

Comment: i solve it using OnClick attribute in Xml instead of image_avatar.setOnClickListener , thank you.